# problemas con formulario (in-line)

Tags: html, html5, bootstrap, formularios

Buen día a todos, estoy realizando una labor social para una facultad en mi universidad.  y estoy teniendo un problema con un formulario específicamente en esta parte.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero hacer este formulario pero no logro hacerlo dentro del mismo contenedor. uso form-inline pero solo me permite hacer hacer una linea y no puedo seguir hacia abajo. alguna idea de como puedo resolver este inconveniente?

btw: soy nuevo en esto.

Ejemplo del código

```
 <section class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-center bg-yellow">
      <br>
      <div class="small-box bg-navy">
        <div class="inner">
          <form class="form-inline" action="/action_page.php">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="email">Email address:</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="pwd">Password:</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>   
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mira no tengo bootstrap instalado, pero porque no pruebas algo del estilo:

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-center bg-yellow">
            <br>
            <div class="small-box bg-navy">
                <div class="inner">
                    <form class="form-inline" action="/action_page.php">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="nombre">Email address:</label>
                                    <input type="nombre" class="form-control" id="nombre">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="apellidos">Password:</label>
                                    <input type="apellidos" class="form-control" id="apellidos">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

La idea es meter dentro del formulario otro div con la clase **row** y maquetarlo ahí con el sistema de 12 **columnas** de bootstrap

Prueba eso que te he dicho, y sino, pues prueba tu a intentar crear una row dentro del `<form>`

Aun así, incluso más cómodo aún, crea tu tu propio **css**, para estas situaciones la verdad es que es muchísimo mejor.